# Different compilation version jar file in classpath

Tags: java

I have my java source code which I want to compile with `1.5` compiler which has a dependency with a jar file which is `1.6` compatible.
I could successfully compile my java code with below command -

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin>javac -source 1.5 -target 1.5 -bootclasspa
th "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar" -classpath "C:\Users\usr1\Documents\Software\jars\commons-io-2.4-bin\commons-io-2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar"
 Test.java
```

Now I will run with `Java 1.8` which is very much ok. Java executable will not have any issues.

But I would like to know will there by any unforeseen issues with compiling my source code with `1.5` compiler having `1.6` compatible jar file in classpath.

Side Note: This is not something hypothetical out of mind, but a use case of my project.

Comment: Yes, this can break if the Java 6 code calls methods which aren't available in Java 5. You'll most likely find out when the code is running. I'm not going to ask why you run on Java 5...

Comment: All versions of Java older than 1.8 are not supported any more. Why do you want to compile against 1.5?

Comment: When I execute, I do execute with 1.8. That's not gonna problem.
I am more curious about compilation..

Comment: I would like to compile my code against 1.5 because we support WAS 6.1 which is bundled with 1.5

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server#Version_6.1), WAS 6.1 is almost ten years old.  If you have the power to use something newer, use something newer.

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view ,in your case you shall get no issues.
When you compile a java file containing code from jar file then what the compiler might do is to replace the method call with the method signature which is present in the jar file.
Later at runtime it tries to load the exact method call from the jar file.
Hence you see , only exception that you can receive is probably at the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

if you try running java 1.6 in java 1.5 you will probably get a java minmax error
but still you can compail in 1.5 if you code doesn't have any 1.6 specific code

Comment: Your reply is correct  but completely out of context with the question asked.